# Problem with a Arduino exercise and state

Tags: arduino, state

In this part of the code, I need to turn on two leds if the button is pressed for a continuous period of time of over 2 seconds. I need this code for a complexer exercise but I can't understand why it won't pass to etat_choix. (code right below)

```
const int ledmode1 = 10;
const int ledmode2 = 11;

const int buttonin = 4; 
const int eteint = 0;
const int etat_choix = 1;

bool etat = 0;
bool debut = 0;
bool old_buttonin = 0;

unsigned long temps = 0;
unsigned long time1 = 0;

 
void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledmode1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledmode2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonin,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  temps = millis();
  if (etat == eteint){
    old_buttonin = buttonin;
    if (buttonin == HIGH and debut == 0) {
      time1 = millis();
    }
    if (buttonin == HIGH) {
     debut = 1;
    }
    else if (old_buttonin == HIGH and buttonin == LOW ){
      debut = 0;
    }
    if ( temps > time1 + 2000 and debut == 1) {
      etat = etat_choix;
      time1 = 0;
      debut = 0;
    }
  }
  else if (etat == etat_choix) {
    digitalWrite(ledmode1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledmode2,HIGH);
    
  }
```

Comment: What have you done so far to debug this? Why are you mixing `bool` and `int` types? For example, why do you have `etat = etat_choix;` when `etat` is a `bool` and `etat_choix` is an `int`? Where is the rest of your `loop` that shows how `buttonin` is assigned?

Comment: First of all etat_choix is not a variable, it just to simplify the reading and understanding of the code.(etat in French means state(should have translated)). I don't understand what you mean by "Where is the rest of your loop that shows how buttonin is assigned".

Comment: i am trying to debug it

Comment: You have `const int etat_choix = 1;` and `bool etat = 0;` and you assign `etat = etat_choix`. That's what I mean about the mixed types. Although it may actually work, it doesn't make sense. `bool` is intended to be used with values `true` and `false` (for readability). About your loop, the code you show doesn't have the closing `}` for `loop()` and I seen nowhere in which `buttonin` is *assigned* a value, so I assumed you didn't show all of your loop code. If you are showing all of it, then the fact that `buttonin` is never assigned is a problem.

Comment: @lurker: I see `const int buttonin = 4; ` and guess confusing pin numbers and states is another problem here. But that's just a guess.